# "$__" is not allowed

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I use Joi for validation.
I send a POST request with Postman and get this response `"$__" is not allowed`.

Can't find any reference related to that.

[image: Post function][image: validation function][image: postman]

Comment: How did you install and require the Joi?

Comment: Customer is Mongoose model, isn't it? You should validate it's object representation, not internal document representation. Likely `validate(customer.toObject())`. Please, let know if this works. Also, validating Mongoose models with external validator doesn't make much sense. Mongoose provides additional overhead exactly to take care of such things.

Comment: @estus No need to use Joi anymore?

Comment: @FransiscoWijaya Likely yes. Mongoose does validation. That's one of main purposes of ORM. Is it Mongoose? The question doesn't have an appropriate tag, while it's very relevant here.

Comment: Sorry im noob, i will provide an update tomorrow to see if it's work

Comment: Can you paste code rather than use screenshots? Thanks

Comment: solved already. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Joi, mongoose has its own validator.
Write your own validation on the Model declaration.

Comment: Yes - Mongoose has its own validator. But the purpose of Joi is to validate the incoming request body. and the purpose of mongoose validation to validate data before storing it into mongo. So they should be used as and how to serve the purpose.