# I keep getting ($__ is not allowed) error while validating a perfectly valid object

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, joi

I using Node.js API's, I also use Joi package to validate my entries , but I keep getting error ($__ is not allowed) while the form I submit seems to be perfectly valid.
I have searched a lot but couldn't find any useful solution.

Joi version is use is 14.3.1,
and the node version is 14.3.1

here is the schema :

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
    price : Joi.object().required().allow(),
    description : Joi.string().min(15).max(400).required().allow(),
    isFavorate : Joi.boolean().required().allow(),
    place: Joi.object().required().allow(),
    tags : Joi.array().required().allow(),
    isDeliveryAvailable : Joi.boolean().required().allow(),
    rating: Joi.number().min(0).required().allow(),
    images : Joi.required().allow(),
    secondHand : Joi.required().allow()
})
    return Joi.validate(item , schema) ;
}
```

The form data:

```
{
    "name" : "an image",
    "price" : {
        "IQD" : 1000,
        "USD" : 10
    },
    "place" : {
        "name" : "fata rap"
    },
    "description" : "some item safas dfsa d",
    "isFavorate" : true,
    "tags": ["some tag 1", "tag 2"],
    "isDeliveryAvailable": true,
    "rating" : 4,
    "comments":["comment 1" , "comment 2"],
    "variants": [
        {"name": "item one variant one", "price":{
            "IQD":1000,
            "USD": 1}
        },
            {"name": "item one variant tow", "price":{
            "IQD":2000,
            "USD": 2}
        },
            {"name": "item one variant three", "price":{
            "IQD":1000,
            "USD": 1}
        }
        ],
    "category" : "5d479c60e35db51e3084c007",
    "secondHand" : "true"


}
```

the model :

```
const Item = mongoose.model('Items',new  mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type : String,
        required: true,
        minlength : 5,
        maxlength : 50
    },

    price : {
        type: Object,
        IQD: {type : Number, required : true, min : 0},
        USD:  {type : Number, required : true, min : 0 }
    },

    description : {
        type : String,
        minlength : 15,
        maxlength : 400,
        required : true
    },

    isFavorate: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required : true
    },

    place : {
      name : {
        type : Object,
        required : true,
      }
    },

    tags : {
        type : [String],
        required : true,
    },

    isDeliveryAvailable : {
        type : Boolean,
        default: true,
        required: true
    },

    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min : 0,
        max : 10,
        required : true
    },

    comments : {
        type : [String],
    },

    images: {
        type: [Buffer],
        requied : true
    },

    imageURLArray : [String],

    variants: [Object],

    category: {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },

    subcategory: {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Subcategory'
    },

    secondHand : {
        type : Boolean,
        required : true,
        default : false
    }

}));
```

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Here you can find a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086751/is-not-allowed.

Comment: Hi Andrea. Thank you for your help. I have already looked into that link. It says the solution is not to use Joi at all. That doesn't resolve my problem since I really need to use Joi.

Comment: No, I'm facing the same issue and the purpose of using Joi is for client-side validation, after that we can always use Mongoose validation but Joi is for client-side validation.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhoSZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhoSZ.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose `item = new Item(formData);` which makes the item a Mongoose object. 
If you do this:

```
Joi.validate(item._doc, schema);
```

then `"$__" is not allowed` error is not observed. This looks a bit hacky, though. If I were you, I'd probably use Mongoose to validate before saving to database and perhaps use Joi just to validate user input.

Comment: Thank you Denny. Although the solution doesn't work and gives me the error(no such directory or file ) error. But I think the way to go is not to use Joi validation at all.

Comment: @Dyary, I've tested with mongoose version `5.6.8`. Still, `._doc` is an internal prop, so not a good idea anyways.

Answer (score 0):

once you validate the schema through mongoose the their is no need to validate through Joi . if you  remove Joi validation then error will be gone.